# Animating view on visibility change

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using the code snippet given below to show/hide a view on click inside a RecyclerView. The issue is that after the first show/hide cycle, the view shows up for a moment then disappears. This keeps happening till I restart the activity.

```
public void changeVisibility(final View view, boolean makeVisible)
{
    if (makeVisible)
    {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.setAlpha(0.0f);

        view.animate().alpha(1.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        view.animate()
                .alpha(0.0f)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                    {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to set visibility gone in xml?

Comment: @DEADMC The visibility for the view is GONE by default in xml.

Comment: I guess you have to setAlpha(0.0f); first to gone object and only then make it visible, probably it is *that* moment.

Comment: Do you do this inside the RecyclerView? It might be that it gets the state from getView after you do it (from "cache") I guess you have a pojo associated to the row, try putting a boolean for visibility in it and update accordingly in getview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason because you set `onAnimationEnd` after the first round of show/hide of the view.

You should remove the `listener` when you don't need it anymore. Add this:

```
view.setListener(null);
```

to your `if (makeVisible)` block should work! ;)